# Is there a general way to integrate: $\int(f(x))^ndx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there a general way to integrate: $\int(f(x))^ndx$ ?

For example: integrating $\int (x^2+ x^{-\frac 15})^3dx$ without expanding the parenthesis?

Note: preferably indefinite integrals.

Comment: Nope.   Way too many different kinds of functions have different behaviors when raised to powers

Comment: I see, that's a bit sad... @Alan

Comment: For large n in the case of a definite integral there exists general methods to derive asymptotic series.

Comment: @CountIblis can you name or link those methods please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent